# WP: How to center two images (they change by hover effect)?

Tags: html, css

I display an image which changing by another image if the mouse is over it (hover). This works perfectly, but the image is not centered. Here is the code I using:

**HTML:**

```
<figure><a><img class="hover" src="nachher.jpg" alt="" width="60%" />
<img class="nohover" src="vorher.jpg" alt="" width="60%/" /></a>
<figcaption>some text here</figcaption></figure
```

**CSS:**

```
img.nohover {border:0;} 
img.hover {border:0;display:none;} 
a:hover img.hover {display:inline;} 
a:hover img.nohover {display:none;}
```

The question is: How can i center the image(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would move `width: 60%` to the `figure`, then make the images `width: 100%`. Then you can

```css
img.nohover {border:0;} 
img.hover {border:0;display:none;} 
a:hover img.hover {display:inline;} 
a:hover img.nohover {display:none;}
figure {
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <a><img class="hover" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C22p.jpg" alt="" />
    <img class="nohover" src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" alt="" /></a>
  <figcaption>some text here</figcaption>
</figure>
```

use `margin: auto` on `figure` to center it horizontally.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Problem solved! :) I only not used img {width: 100%;} because it increased all other images, too.

Comment: @Oliver awesome, yeah the same would apply to `figure`, but I don't know how to limit it with a class or whatever since I don't know what the rest of your site looks like.